# Python converting a list in a nested dictionary into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have the following dictionary

```
test = {'data': [
  {'actions': [
    {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '16'},
    {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '16'},
    {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '16'}],
   'spend': '13.59',
   'date_start': '2023-02-07',
   'date_stop': '2023-02-07'},
  {'actions': [
    {'action_type': 'comment', 'value': '5'},
    {'action_type': 'onsite_conversion.post_save', 'value': '1'},
    {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '465'},
    {'action_type': 'post', 'value': '1'},
    {'action_type': 'post_reaction', 'value': '20'},
    {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '4462'},
    {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '4954'},
    {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '4954'}],
   'spend': '214.71',
   'date_start': '2023-02-07',
   'date_stop': '2023-02-07'}]}
```

And I am trying to convert it where each element after action type is a pandas DataFrame column, and the value as row. Something like

```
link_click post_engagement page_engagement   spend comment onsite_conversion ...
        16              16              16   13.59     N/A               N/A
       465            4954            4954  214.71       5                 1
```

I understand that the first list does not have comment, post, etc, and the rows would be N/A. How do I manage this complicated data structure?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to work this, but you might try using [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), then you might need to do a pivot. Or I suppose you could do it manually :| i.e. use Python structures like list comprehensions and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this function:

```py
# import pandas as pd

def tabulate_actions(actionsList:list, returnDf=False):
    aTbl = [{
        a['action_type']: a['value'] for a in al['actions']
        # if isinstance(a, dict) and all([k in a for k in ['action_type', 'value']])
    } for al in actionsList
    # if isinstance(al, dict) and isinstance(al.get('actions'), list)
    ]
    return pd.DataFrame(aTbl) if returnDf else aTbl
## uncomment the conditions if you're unsure of your data structure
```

`tabulate_actions(test['data'])` should return this list of dictionaries:

> ```py
> [{'link_click': '16',
>   'post_engagement': '16',
>   'page_engagement': '16'},
>  {'comment': '5',
>   'onsite_conversion.post_save': '1',
>   'link_click': '465',
>   'post': '1',
>   'post_reaction': '20',
>   'video_view': '4462',
>   'post_engagement': '4954',
>   'page_engagement': '4954'}]
> ```

and passing `returnDf=True` should make it return a DataFrame:

[image: opdf]